# Curl sh a wget list?

Tags: linux, curl, centos

I have a list of wget stuff that I want to be installed. I used to use a command but I can't remember what it was. I remember I used to type something like this and it would install wget in the .txt file. "curl sh list.txt".

I was wondering if anyone knew the command to install a list of wget commands in a txt file.

For example I have a txt file that contains the stuff I post below, and instead of installing them all one by one, I would use a command that would run the list and install it all for me.

This would be the txt file.

```
yum -y update
wget http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=68233 -O java.rpm
rpm -Uvh java.rpm
yum -y groupinstall Desktop
yum install -y nano unzip xkill firefox tigervnc-server
vncserver && vncserver -kill :1
sed -i 's/twm/startxfce4/g' ~/.vnc/xstartup
vncserver
rm -rf *.rpm
wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u51-b16/jdk-8u51-linux-x64.rpm"
```

Comment: If I squint a bit, it looks like you're asking ["*how do I run this shell script?*"](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0010.php). I can't begin to guess what curl has to do with it, or what "installing wget commands in a text file" might mean.

Comment: One such combination is: `curl http://example.com/script.sh -o - | sh` which will download the file, pipe the output of the response to stdout which is then piped to `sh` for execution.